# x86 shellcode leads to segmentation fault

Tags: shellcode

I want to execute `execve("/bin/dash", &"/bin/dash", NULL)` on Ubuntu 64 bit with the following 32 bit shellcode:

```
global _start

_start:
    xor eax, eax ; set eax = 0 to push a null without using 0x0
    push eax ; eax = null pointer

    mov edx, esp ; edx = null pointer

    ; push '/bin/dash' into stack
    ; but length of string actually needs to be divisible by 4,
    ; otherwise there will be a 0x00 in the string, so:
    ; push null pointer first, then
    ; push '////bin/dash' into stack
    push eax ; eax = null pointer
    push 0x68736164
    push 0x2f6e6962
    push 0x2f2f2f2f

    mov ebx, esp ; ebx = string pointer '////bin/dash'
    push ebx
    mov ecx, esp ; ecx = pointer to string pointer
    mov eax, 0xfffffff4 
    not eax ; eax = 0xb = pointer to execve
    int 0x80 ; interrupt system call
```

I compile the assembler code with the following line and then extract the machine code:

```
$ nasm -felf32 shellcode.asm -o x.o && ld -m elf_i386 x.o -o shellcode
$ objdump -d shellcode -M intel -s
shellcode:     file format elf32-i386

Contents of section .text:
 8048060 31c05089 e2506864 61736868 62696e2f  1.P..Phdashhbin/
 8048070 682f2f2f 2f89e353 89e1b8f4 fffffff7  h////..S........
 8048080 d0cd80                               ..P             

Disassembly of section .text:

08048060 <_start>:
 8048060:   31 c0                   xor    eax,eax
 8048062:   50                      push   eax
 8048063:   89 e2                   mov    edx,esp
 8048065:   50                      push   eax
 8048066:   68 64 61 73 68          push   0x68736164
 804806b:   68 62 69 6e 2f          push   0x2f6e6962
 8048070:   68 2f 2f 2f 2f          push   0x2f2f2f2f
 8048075:   89 e3                   mov    ebx,esp
 8048077:   53                      push   ebx
 8048078:   89 e1                   mov    ecx,esp
 804807a:   b8 f4 ff ff ff          mov    eax,0xfffffff4
 804807f:   f7 d0                   not    eax
 8048081:   cd 80                   int    0x80
```

Then I'm trying to execute my shellcode with this c file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *shellcode = "\x31\xc0\x50\x89\xe2\x50\x68\x64\x61\x73\x68\x68\x62\x69\x6e\x2f\x68\x2f\x2f\x2f\x2f\x89\xe3\x53\x89\xe1\xb8\xf4\xff\xff\xff\xf7\xd0\xcd\x80";

int main()
{
    fprintf(stdout,"Length: %d\n",strlen(shellcode));
    (*(void  (*)()) shellcode)();
}
```

I compile this file with:

```
gcc -fno-stack-protector test_shellcode.c -o test_shellcode
```

But this leads to a segmentation fault.
I debugged my shellcode with gdb and it looks like my shellcode is working fine but the first line that uses the register `al` or `ah` leads to the segmentation fault.

How can I fix that?

Comment: I think is missing the address of your /bin/dash, you are referring to some address that don't exists on your test_shellcode binary, check also the registers (info reg in gdb). However, this question is more appropriate to https://stackoverflow.com/ forum or in https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @camp0 what address do you think I am missing? I debugged the shellcode and all registers seemed to be fine. The segmentation fault happens outside of my shellcode

Comment: The same question with an answer can now be found here: [x86 shellcode leads to segmentation fault](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/21352/x86-shellcode-leads-to-segmentation-fault)